# Select Query Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

My Table Structure is like below:

```
Carrier Terminal    timestamp1
1          1        21-Mar-17
2        101        21-Mar-17
3          2        21-Mar-17
4        202        21-Mar-17
5          3        21-Mar-17
6        303        21-Mar-17
```

where carrier

```
flight 1,2 = Delta
flight 3,4 = Air France
flight 5,6 = Lufthanse
```

and

```
Terminal 1,101 = T1
terminal 2,202 = T2
terminal 3,303 = T3
```

I am trying output like below:

```
count(Delta), count(Air France), count(Lufthansa), terminal as column output
  2, 0, 0, T1
  0, 2, 0, T2
  0, 0, 2, T3
```

I have started like this

```
select count(Delta), count(Air France), count(Lufthansa), terminal
from table_name
where timestamp between '01-Mar-18 07.00.00.000000 AM' and '30-Mar-18 07.59.59.999999 AM'
```

I am trying to write a query to have a count of different carriers flown through a particular day for each terminal

Any Advise will be highly appreciated

Comment: How do you know which flights are associated with which carriers?  I think there is something about your data model that you are not telling us.

Comment: with t as (
select 1 as Flight, 1 as Gate, to_date('21-Mar-17','dd-Mon-yyyy') from dual
union all
select 2 as Flight, 101 as Gate, to_date('21-Mar-17','dd-Mon-yyyy') from dual
union all
select 3 as Flight, 2 as Gate, to_date('21-Mar-17','dd-Mon-yyyy') from dual
union all
select 4 as Flight, 202 as Gate, to_date('21-Mar-17','dd-Mon-yyyy') from dual
union all
select 5 as Flight, 3 as Gate, to_date('21-Mar-17','dd-Mon-yyyy') from dual
union all
select 6 as Flight, 303 as Gate, to_date('21-Mar-17','dd-Mon-yyyy') from dual
)
select * from t;

Comment: I am trying to write query like below (It is not correct though):

 

select count(delta),count(Air_france), count(lufthansa), Terminal

from

(

select

case

     when flight in (1,2) then 'Delta'

     when flight in (3,4) then 'Air_France'

     else 'lufthansa',

case

     when gate in (1,101) then 'T1'

    when gate in (2,202) then 'T2'

     else 'T3'

from t;

 

Any Advise would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a whole lot of assumptions for this to work... I've extracted all the rules you've mentioned in your text and I've assumed that those structures are are already in place. Otherwise, let us know :)

```
with flights(carrier, terminal, departure) as(
    select 1, 1,    timestamp '2017-03-01 01:00:00' from dual union all
    select 2, 101,  timestamp '2017-03-01 02:00:00' from dual union all
    select 3, 2,    timestamp '2017-03-01 03:00:00' from dual union all
    select 4, 202,  timestamp '2017-03-01 04:00:00' from dual union all
    select 5, 3,    timestamp '2017-03-01 05:00:00' from dual union all
    select 6, 303,  timestamp '2017-03-01 06:00:00' from dual
)
,carriers(carrier, carrier_name) as(
    select 1,   'Delta'         from dual union all
    select 2,   'Delta'         from dual union all
    select 3,   'Air France'    from dual union all
    select 4,   'Air France'    from dual union all
    select 5,   'Lufthanse'     from dual union all
    select 6,   'Lufthanse'     from dual
)
,terminals(terminal, terminal_name) as(
    select 1,   'T1' from dual union all
    select 101, 'T1' from dual union all
    select 2,   'T2' from dual union all
    select 202, 'T2' from dual union all
    select 3,   'T3' from dual union all
    select 303, 'T3' from dual
)
select terminal_name
      ,count(case when carrier_name = 'Delta'      then 1 end) as "Delta"
      ,count(case when carrier_name = 'Air France' then 1 end) as "Air France"
      ,count(case when carrier_name = 'Lufthanse'  then 1 end) as "Lufthanse"
  from flights   f 
  join carriers  c using(carrier)
  join terminals t using(terminal)
 where departure >= timestamp '2017-03-01 00:00:00' 
   and departure <  timestamp '2017-04-01 00:00:00'
 group by terminal_name
 order by terminal_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with
  t ( flight, gate, ts ) as (
    select 1,   1, to_timestamp('21-Mar-17', 'dd-Mon-rr') from dual union all
    select 2, 101, to_timestamp('21-Mar-17', 'dd-Mon-rr') from dual union all
    select 3,   2, to_timestamp('21-Mar-17', 'dd-Mon-rr') from dual union all
    select 4, 202, to_timestamp('21-Mar-17', 'dd-Mon-rr') from dual union all
    select 5,   3, to_timestamp('21-Mar-17', 'dd-Mon-rr') from dual union all
    select 6, 303, to_timestamp('21-Mar-17', 'dd-Mon-rr') from dual
  )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins below this line. Use your actual table and column names.
select   count (case when flight in (1, 2) then 1 end) as delta
     ,   count (case when flight in (3, 4) then 1 end) as air_france
     ,   count (case when flight in (5, 6) then 1 end) as lufthansa
     ,   case when gate in (1, 101) then 'T1'
              when gate in (2, 202) then 'T2'
              when gate in (3, 303) then 'T3' end as terminal
from     t
where    ts between '21-Mar-17 02.00.00.000000 AM' and '21-Mar-17 10.00.00.000000 AM'
group by case when gate in (1, 101) then 'T1'
              when gate in (2, 202) then 'T2'
              when gate in (3, 303) then 'T3' end
order by terminal
;
```

```
     DELTA AIR_FRANCE  LUFTHANSA TERMINAL
---------- ---------- ---------- --------
         2          0          0 T1
         0          2          0 T2
         0          0          2 T3
```